Present Perfect + Before + Present Perfect vs. Past Simple / What is the difference?

KOTB: (Voiceover) Behind the shouting, behind the intense focus on basketball, coach is busy doing for these girls what he's been doing for 26 years. Shaping young lives. His reach extends well beyond the court.
KOTB: So what do you monitor outside of basketball?
Mr. INSELL: Everything - what they do in the community, their academics, you know, and in some cases maybe their social lives, you know, with their boyfriends.
KOTB: Isn't that sort of going just way, way, way, way, way overboard?
Mr. INSELL: I don't think so. In some cases they need to know that coach is there. Many times they've called me before they've called their parents.
KOTB: (Voiceover) Like Sam Houston. She's been in trouble before. A few years ago, coach kicked her off the team for lousy grades and a bad attitude. She got her act together, though, and he gave her a second chance. Sam will never forget it.

NBC Dateline: A Season of Hope - Shelbyville Eagelettes Overcome Personal Challenges To Win 10th Straight Championship (2004)

WILLIAMS: See, that's why you went to Princeton and I went to community college in New Jersey. But that's a separate topic. How about the dress earlier today?
Ms. GIVHAN: The swearing-in dress?
WILLIAMS: Yes. Your opinion and the designer.
Ms. GIVHAN: The designer, Isabel Toledo, Cuban-born, has been in the states for a very long time. I thought it was a great dress.
(Voiceover) And what I loved about it is that it actually looked regal. It made her look exceptional on the Capitol steps. And other first ladies in recent years, it seems like they've needed a little bit more time before they've been willing to kind of stop trying to pretend like they're everyone else and play down their fashion sense. She really seemed to feel comfortable and to embrace that sense of "Everyone's looking at me."

NBC Dateline: THE INAUGURATION OF BARACK OBAMA (HOST: Brian Williams) (2009)

As I said before, I think the great diversity of this nation can and must be a source of strength as we face the challenges that lie ahead. I have spent several hours, already, especially in the last three days, working with Senator Gore, with Mr. Christopher, and with others discussing potential Cabinet appointments. I have spent an enormous amount of time with Senator Gore and with others discussing the kinds of things we want these departments to do. I think that too often in the past potential president-elects have been in a rush to fill the Cabinet positions before they decided whether they wanted these departments to pursue a different mission than had been pursued in the past, and without considering perhaps, how these departments should fit one with the other.

CBS Special: PRESIDENT-ELECT CLINTON HOLDS HIS FIRST PRESS CONFERENCE, ANSWERING QUESTIONS ON A VARIETY OF ISSUES (1992)

I gravitate to books about space travel and biographies of people who gave it all up for an existence in the South of France, say, or the South Sea Islands. In meetings, I find I can't listen to meaningless drivel anymore without wanting to get up and leave. That's a significant liability. PowerPoint presentations in particular put me into a sleep so deep it involves drooling. The smallest things irritate me way too much, also. I'm up every night at 3 A.M. wondering why I'm up every night at 3 A.M. No matter how small the potential snafu or fubar situation, it rears up and seizes my imagination like a golem. I need some relief. I've been at this 25 years. I may need to retire. On the other hand, I see people who have retired before they were physically unable to work anymore, and frankly, they give me the willies. All those healthy, fit men with suntans and golf clubs and white, toothy grins that you will see elsewhere in this issue, I am sure.

Magazine Fortune: HOW TO RETIRE WHILE STILL WORKING (2007)
If someone could explain to me why the present perfect is used sometimes and sometimes the past simple in situations like these, after the preposition before in an adverbial clause?
Is there any difference in meaning or they are interchangeable?

'Simplification of tenses' (though arguably past perfect is a construction rather than a real tense usage) often involves using past simple for present perfect provided clarity isn't thereby compromised. I'd say either is available in each of your examples, though 'people who have retired before they have been physically unable to work anymore' seems especially clunky.

Does this answer your question? Is "He was arrested because he murdered his neighbour." a simplification of "He was arrested because he had murdered his neighbour."?

This is all transcribed speech, most of which is fine. There are a few odd things here and there.

I didn't downvote your question. But you certainly shouldn't be telling anybody how to vote. //"He was arrested after he murdered his neighbour." a simplification of "He was arrested after he had murdered his neighbour." shows the same sequencing of events: the 'because' forces sequentiality (and also adds reason). And "He had been well known before he had been on television." ...  "He was well known before he was on  television." are both similarly available. So I certainly close-voted.

In the first two examples, the simple past tense would also be acceptable for the second verb. "They have called me before they called" or "before calling their parents".

As implied by the first comment, native Anglophones prefer to avoid complex verb forms (more than most learners, I'd say). So in the last two examples, we naturally switch from Past Perfect to Simple Past once the first verb form has unambiguously established the temporal frame. The basic principle is always Don't use Perfect forms unless you need them (and at all costs, Don't overuse Perfect verb forms).

@FumbleFingers You're saying that "...president-elects have been in a rush to fill the Cabinet positions before they had decided whether they wanted..." and  "...I see people who have retired before they had been physically unable to work..." are equally possible?

Why would you think that? Both your examples in the above comment are completely invalid, because you're switching from Present Perfect to Past Perfect. I said we often switch from Past Perfect to Simple Past. Or in the examples in your last comment, Present Perfect to Simple Present: 1) ...president-elects have been in a rush to fill the Cabinet positions before they decide whether they want... and 2) ...I see people who have retired before they are physically unable to work...

@FumbleFingers Yes, now I see it! I didn't understand you correctly.

bear in mind it's only a tendency to avoid repeating more complex verb forms. Obscure stylistic considerations may come into play, so 1) before they have decided (or before they decide) and 2) before they were (or before they have become) are at least possible options above. But when in doubt, always choose the simplest tense you think might feasibly be acceptable, and you'll be wrong far less often than if you spend a lot of effort trying to find the "correct" verb form.

You are right. "they've called me before they've called their parents" would be better as "they called me before they've called." It's neither wrong nor high art, but speech, as per @Lambie.
